# How do I remove a function from the lein repl?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, vimclojure

During a lein REPL session, I may define a number of functions. However, sometimes I would want the session to 'forget' them - for example when I execute (run-all-tests), this highlights failures from tests that I no longer need. Is there a way to remove functions from the session, or to clean it, without restarting?

Comment: note: I am connecting to the lein repl through the vim-fireplace plugin, and running tests with the 'cpR' command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `ns-unmap` as described on the Clojure namespaces page http://clojure.org/namespacesuser>

```
(defn foo [x] (inc x))                    
#'user/foo     
user> (foo 3)       
4                                                                                
user> (ns-unmap *ns* 'foo)     
nil
user> (foo 3)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Is there a similar function to 'unmap' all functions?

Comment: you can get a list of all the function with ns-map. then unmap them.